# How to compare multiple variables to the same value(empty) in Perl?

Tags: perl

So, i have a few variables that i need to check for emptyness, and it would be nicer and easier if i could do it in some way other than comparing each and every one like this

```
if ($var1 ne "" && $var2 ne "" && $var3 ne"")
```

So is there a better way?

PS: If anybody is going to propose to put them in a hash and loop through them, they are already in a hash, but they're not alone there, i have a lot of other values there(all are needed together later in the code, so spliting it wouldn't be easy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're in a hash, you can access them as a slice and grep them:

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    "to_test"      => "",
    "to_ignore"    => "some value",
    "also_to_test" => "",
    "not_to_test"  => "content here",
);

my @keys = qw ( to_test also_to_test );

unless ( grep { $_ ne '' } @hash{@keys} ) {
    print "Keys are all empty: @keys\n";
}
```

You could do a similar thing with  named variables, but that's perhaps not quite as elegant.

Comment: Yeah, that was the one I was thinking of!

Answer (score 6):

You could make use of `List::Util::all` like this

```
use List::Util 'all';

if ( all { $_ ne '' } $var1, $var2, $var3 ) { ... }
```

but I would expect to see it in the form you show

If you are testing the values of a hash then you should use a hash slice to select them

```
if ( all { $_ ne '' } @hash{@keys_to_check} ) { ... }
```

Comment: Your snipper works just as well as the one i've accepted as an answer, but i try to minimize my external dependencies due to portability reasons(the code i'm writing will be used on multiple different computers by multiple different users, and having to install a libraries is kind of a pain in the arse), sooo nothing personal in not accepting your answer :)

Comment: `List::Util` is core in perl as of 5.7.3

Comment: @AdrianTodorov: You are welcome to accept whichever solution is best for you. I stopped chasing points a long time ago as I believe it interferes with writing a good answer. But you should be aware that every Perl installation includes a select number of *core* modules which will be available with that version of Perl wherever it is installed. `List::Util` has been a core module since version 5.8 over twenty years ago and you shouldn't hesitate to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with inverted logic,

```
if (!grep {$_ eq ""} $var1, $var2, $var3) { .. }
```

If there are too many variables, you can put their scalar references into an array, and perform `grep` on it,

```
my @sref = \($var1, $var2, $var3);
if (!grep {${$_} eq ""} @sref) { .. }
```

`${$_}` or `$$_` dereferences scalar reference.

Answer (score -2):

If those are in hash, then create an array with the keys you want to test and loop through them checking if value in hash is empty.

Comment: Please write an example to explain.